# Android unit testing a constructor that throws exception

Tags: android, json, unit-testing, exception, junit4

I recently started coding my first android project using Android Studio 3.1.2 and SDK 19.

Now I started writing tests for my java code, and I want to check in particular, if a constructor that takes a `JSONObject` and creates a `Worker` object, works, but I'm unsure how to handle the case, if a `JSONException` gets thrown, though i want to let the test fail, if an invalid JSONObject is passed.

This is the `Worker` object:

```
public class Worker {

    //MARK: - fields
    private String name;
    private String id;
    private String phone;
    private String team;

    //MARK: - constructor
    public Worker(JSONObject json) {
        try {
            this.id = json.getString("id");
            this.name = json.getString("name");
            this.phone = json.getString("phone");
            this.team = json.getString("team");
        } catch(JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //MARK: - getters
    //...
}
```

So my question is, how can I test in particular, if the constructor returns a `Worker` as expected, or throws an exception? I'm using `junit4` for non-instrumented unit tests. Thanks in forward.

**EDIT:**

The according `JSONObject` I got from my API looks like this:

`{"name":"procra","team":"developers","phone":"123456789","id":"42"}`

Comment: The real question is: Why is your code succeeding when a `JSONException` occurs? Even if your test is able to ascertain that the `Worker` object was not correctly initialized, your actual code will not be able to do that.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen sorry, i forgot to mention, that if the constructor throws an exception, a dummy Worker (with all fields nullified) will be created. My catch block is in fact a little bit longer but for simplicity i sourced that out to another method that checks, if the created worker is a dummy

Comment: Then I don't really understand the problem. In your test, pass a faulty `JSONObject`, and check whether the returned object corresponds to your expectations.

Comment: This is in fact the easy part of the story. I had also difficulties to create a valid `JSONObject` inside the test, though `json.put(key, value)` has to wrapped in a try-catch also, if I do this in the particular testing method, it will interfere with the exception thrown by the constructor of `Worker`

Comment: The constructor of worker does not throw any exception.

Comment: Take a look at my code again, or did you mean, because it's instantly catched?

Comment: I don't need to look at your code again. Your constructor does *not* throw an exception. Otherwise its signature would be `public Worker(JSONObject json) throws JSONException`

Comment: I understand, I will refactor my test a little and try it again, thank you